# Proof of Stirling number symmetric formulas

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, stirling-numbers

I'm looking for a reference to a proof of formulas 6.26 and 6.27 in [Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf):
$\def\sone#1#2{\left[#1\atop #2\right]}
\def\stwo#1#2{\left\{#1\atop #2\right\}}
$
$$ \stwo{n}{n-m} = \sum_k \binom{m-n}{m+k}\binom{m+n}{n+k}
\sone{m+k}{k} $$

$$\sone{n}{n-m} = \sum_k \binom{m-n}{m+k}\binom{m+n}{n+k}
\stwo{m+k}{k}$$

Answer (score 6):

$\def\sone#1#2{\left[#1\atop #2\right]}
\def\stwo#1#2{\left\{#1\atop #2\right\}}
$

These formulas can be proved by Lagrange interpolation, using the fact that
$\stwo{n}{n-m}$ and $\sone{n}{n-m}$ are polynomials in $n$ of degree $2m$. See H. W. Gould, [The Lagrange interpolation formula and Stirling numbers,](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-03/S0002-9939-1960-0114769-1/S0002-9939-1960-0114769-1.pdf) Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 11 (1960), 421–425